# Passing SQL output to Javascript to generate dynamic chart

Tags: php, javascript

My PHP code to retrieve data from SQL and the Javascript code to generate dynamic graph are in the same page(graph.php). I got the SQL result in the JSON array with the following code:

```php
$row = $result->fetch_row()
$row = json_encode($row);
```

My Javascript code :

```js
$(function () {

        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'pie'
            },

            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        distance: -30,
                        color: 'white'
                    }
                }
            },

            series: [{
                data: [
                    ['result1',   44.2],
                    ['result2',       26.6],
                    ['result3',       20],
                    ['result4',    3.1],
                    ['result5',    5.4]
                ]
            }]
        });
    });
```

I want to use that JSON array data from PHP code in Javascript (result1,result2,result3.....).

**Note:** PHP and Javascript codes are in the same page. I am not posting or getting data from another page.

Comment: **print_r** the data returned by `$result->fetch_row()`. that could help

Answer (score 0):

You can using like this,

```
    series: [{
                data:<?php echo $row;//json encoded db data ?>
            }]
```

$row should be a json string.
careful about the json data, it should be in the format of data that you displayed along the script

Comment: is there getting any value for $row outside the script ?

Comment: yes, when I echo the php output or jason output it print the value on the screen.But the value is not transferring to javascript.